# How do I block copy into the original text not overwrite in VI?

Tags: vim

Now, I'm using Linux and VI editor.
During I use VI I have some problem. When I use block copy into the text, that texts are overwrited on the original text.

How do I block copy into the original text not overwrite in VI?

## add screen shot

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Please include sample steps to reproduce your problem, or a screencast showing the problem. What do you select, how do you copy, and where / how to you paste???

Comment: @IngoKarkat I add screenshot

Comment: @IngoKarkat and I use the same manner from Rakib. I hope you know want I want to say you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've yanked a  *blockwise visual selection*, pasting that will *insert* the block at the current position, into the existing text, without adding new lines or shifting existing text downwards. That's the expected behavior; you're effectively handling a square "cutout" of text, separate from the underlying text structure.

If you're handling complete line(s) (and based on your screenshot, you're doing just that), the correct approach is to select and yank the text *linewise*; i.e. use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> for the selection (or `[count]yy` in normal mode, which is faster if you know the number of lines).

If you really need to yank a square block, and paste this as new lines, there are the following approaches:

1. Make space before the paste (e.g. `` 10o<Esc>`[ ``), then paste.
2. Change the mode of the register between yank and paste: `:call setreg('', '', 'al')`
3. Use my [UnconditionalPaste plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3355); it offers (among others) a `glp` command that forces linewise pasting, regardless of how the text was yanked.

Comment: Can we possible to know how much line numbers chose by block wise visual selection? sometimes one page over what I chose it but I always calculate by using calculate the between start line and end line. it's very inconvenient.

Comment: During the selection, its size is displayed in the bottom right corner, e.g. `7x15`.

Answer (score 0):

In vi or vim editor you need to go in visual block mode from command mode using ctrl+v. before going to visual block mode move cursor to the block you want to copy. then press ctrl+v. and select your block.After selecting you just press single y for copy. Then move to cursor end of the file and press p to paste. Thats it.